# How we can add transform rotate and scale simultaneously in .setAttribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I'm working on an SVG an I want to add a scale and rotation transform. The rotate value is dynamic and the scale value is constant.

I tried like this:

```
boxElem.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + rotation + "), scale(0.9)");
```

It is not working. Only the scale value is having an effect. Can anyone tell me how to add multiple properties inside transform in JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setAttribute` will result in adding the attribute `transform` like this :

```
<div transform="rotate(rotation) scale(0.9)"></div>
```

you need to update the `style` of the element :

```
boxElem.style.transform = "rotate(" + rotation + ") scale(0.9)";
```

Comment: it is working fine. In setAttribute `boxElem.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + rotation + ") scale(0.9)");` i removed comma after rotate this is also working.